# concrete5 5.8 Installation issue

Tags: concrete5

Trying to perform an installation of concrete5.8 is resulting in an error as presented in the attached screenshot. At the very end of the error, it also shows:

```
{"error":false}
```

Reloading the page then presents an error stating that there are now 249 tables in the database.

The issue occurs while installing into an empty database table on a Ubuntu/Apache/PHP/mySQL server with all requirements of c5 resulting in ticks prior to proceeding with installation.

[image: Screenshot of failure notice]

Any ideas welcome - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the issue was not present on another server. Upgraded PHP on the original to the latest 5.6 version and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

is your database set to utf-8 ? That error message has lots of strange characters that seem to indicate and encoding issue. Or do you have folders on your server with names using non-latin characters?

Comment: It was/is UTF-8 - upgrading PHP resolved the issue though